# Making MatLab show different plots on two windows

Tags: matlab, plot

So I have written a program in which we want MatLab to plot given data on a scatter plot and bar graph.

I can not really write the complete code here since its pretty long. So I will just describe the problem:

- MatLab plots both graph (scatter and bar graph) but since the command for scatter plot comes after the bar graph, therefore Matlab deletes the bar graph and instead plots and gives out the scatter plot.

IS there a command which would allow Matlab to show both plots on two different windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call [`figure;`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) before plotting a second time. It might look something like this:

```
plot(...); % plot bar graph
figure;
plot(...); % plot scatter plot
```